# Mongoose population in instance methods

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a model with reference to other documents. I would like to have a method in that model that can process data used in the referenced models.

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema
    , deepPopulate = require('mongoose-deep-populate');

var MainSchema = new Schema({
  childs: [{type:Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Child'}], //because many-to-one
  startDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  endDate: {type: Date},
});


MainSchema.methods = {

  retrieveChilds: function(callback) {

    // deepPopulation of childs not possible??

    callback(result);
  },
};

MainSchema.plugin(deepPopulate);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Main', MainSchema);
```

as seen in the code example above, the retrieveChilds function should execute a deepPopulate function on the current Schema. Is this possible or should it happen outside the model? (Which results in duplicate code sometimes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mongoose [instance methods](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods), `this` is the document instance the method is being called on, so you can do this as:

```
MainSchema.methods = {
  retrieveChilds: function(callback) {
    this.deepPopulate('childs.subject.data', callback);
  },
};
```

Then to call it:

```
main.retrieveChilds(function(err, _main) {
    // _main is the same doc instance as main and is populated.
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried this before and it didn't work back then, apparently i forgot that the callback has 2 arguments, the error and the return object. Thank you!